# Pytest - asserts at teardown of class scoped fixture

Tags: python, pytest

I have a parametrized test suite that is organized as a class containing multiple test cases and class-scoped fixture. I'm looking for a way to run some assertions after all tests complete for a given fixture instance. Any ideas on how I can achieve that?

I tried putting `assert` / `pytest.fail` in fixture finalization, but pytest doesn't seem to support this (see example below).

```python
import pytest

class Car:
    def __init__(self, car_model: str):
        pass

class TestCar:
    @pytest.fixture(scope='class', params=["Ford", "Jeep"])
    def car(self, request):
        car = Car(car_model=request.param)
        yield car

        # Here I want some "teardown" checks performed after all tests that depend on the
        # fixture instance have completed. But pytest doesn't seem to support it.
        part_test_ratio = car.used_parts / car.total_parts
#        assert part_test_ratio > 0.9, "At least 90% of parts must be tested!"

    def test_ignition(self, car):
        pass

    def test_steering(self, car):
        pass

    def test_brakes(self, car):
        pass
```

Note: The fixture performs a hefty operation, so I can't create it per each test.

It also raises the question of how such failures could have been reported. I would accept both, either showing it as a separate "dummy" test case with name deduced from the fixture name or retroactively marking all the tests that depend on the fixture as failed.

###### Normal results:

```
PASSED car_test.py::TestCar::test_ignition[Ford]
PASSED car_test.py::TestCar::test_steering[Ford]
PASSED car_test.py::TestCar::test_brakes[Ford]
PASSED car_test.py::TestCar::test_ignition[Jeep]
PASSED car_test.py::TestCar::test_steering[Jeep]
PASSED car_test.py::TestCar::test_brakes[Jeep]
```

###### Option 1:

```
...
PASSED car_test.py::TestCar::test_brakes[Jeep]
FAILED car_test.py::TestCar::car[Jeep]
```

###### Option 2:

```
...
FAILED car_test.py::TestCar::test_ignition[Jeep]
FAILED car_test.py::TestCar::test_steering[Jeep]
FAILED car_test.py::TestCar::test_brakes[Jeep]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The new answer

Without parametrized fixture, the solution would be to use [pytest-ordering](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-order/) plugging, add a new test and mark it as `last` ([example here](https://pytest-ordering.readthedocs.io/en/develop/#other-markers)).

```py
@pytest.mark.last
def test_parts_used_over_margin(self, car):
    assert car.used_parts / car.total_parts > 0.9
```

The problem with parametrized fixtures is, that [pytest only caches one instance of a fixture at a time](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#fixture-scopes). So if you'd add a new test marked as `last`, the order would be:

```
test_ignition["Ford"] <-- creates new 'car' fixture
test_steering["Ford"]
test_brakes["Ford"]
test_ignition["Jeep"] <-- creates new 'car' fixture
test_steering["Jeep"]
test_brakes["Jeep"]
test_parts_used_over_margin["Ford"] <-- creates new 'car' fixture
test_parts_used_over_margin["Jeep"] <-- creates new 'car' fixture
```

The solution is to reorder tests in the way, that the `test_parts_used_over_margin` will be at the end of the group with the same parametrized fixtures. This is pretty complex and I am not aware of any standardized solution for that. So, you'll have to do reordering yourself with `pytest_collection_modifyitems` ([doc](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_collection_modifyitems)). I've created and tested this prototype of `modifyitems` (add this to your conftest.py):

```py
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(session, config, items: list[pytest.Item]):
    tests_to_be_last: list[pytest.Item] = []
    for item in items:
        # Select tests to be reordered.
        if isinstance(item, pytest.Function) \
                and item.originalname == "test_parts_used_over_margin":
            tests_to_be_last.append(item)

    for test in tests_to_be_last:
        # remove those tests from current order
        items.remove(test)

    def get_item_params(item_) -> str | None:
        # nodeid is in format "path-to-test[param-group-identifier]"
        if isinstance(item_, pytest.Function) and "[" in item_.nodeid:
            return item_.nodeid.split("[")[-1].rstrip("]")
        return None

    def find_last_test_with_param(params: str) -> int:
        for item_ in reversed(items):
            if params == get_item_params(item_):
                return items.index(item_)

        # No test with the same parameter was found. Feel free to change the default value
        return 0

    for test in tests_to_be_last:
        test_params = get_item_params(test)
        last_with_same_params_at = find_last_test_with_param(test_params)
        items.insert(last_with_same_params_at + 1, test)
```

---

### The original answer

Create a new test that depends on all other tests, which will check that.

```py
@pytest.mark.depends(on=["test_ignition", ..., "test_brakes"])
def test_parts_used_over_margin(self, car):
    assert car.used_parts / car.total_parts > 0.9
```

Comment: @vojtechchvojka Yeah, this indeed works. But I'm sure you see that unfortunately, this approach is quite bulky, custom tailored and non-elegant. I have a feeling that proper solution requires some features added to either pytest itself or pytest-depends. Don't you think?

Comment: @vvv444 You could also build on the fact, that pytest collects tests in the order in which they are defined [here is a link to test](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/main/testing/python/collect.py#L774) that tests that. So if you define the new test last in the `TestCar` class and don't change the order of tests somewhere else (for example with `pytest-order`), it should work well.